# Java Patterns not understanding

Tags: java, regex

What is the meaning of below pattern in Java Patterns concept?

```
^[\p{Alnum}]{6,7}$
```

I understand it can access 6 to 7 alphanumeric charecter. But what it is the meaning for $ in above format.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: Thanks. I need this format "3AB 45D". That is first 3 Alnum chars and space and 3 Alnum chars. How I can achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the format that you requested( I need this format "3AB 45D". That is first 3 Alnum chars and space and 3 Alnum chars.),

```
^[\\p{Alnum}]{3}\\p{Space}[\\p{Alnum}]{3}$
```

Answer (score 2):

`$` means the end of a line and `^` means the beginning of a line. The [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you mentioned, is called regular expression

Answer (score 1):

`$` means end of string.

If you do not have it in your pattern then it will also match any alphanumeric string of 6 to 7 characters....followed by antyhing

I hope you get that `^` is beginning of the string :)

Answer (score 0):

**Your pattern**

```
^[\p{Alnum}]{6,7}$
```

**Explanation**

```
"^" +              // Assert position at the beginning of the string
"[\\p{Alnum}]" +    // Match a single character present in the list below
                      // A character in the POSIX character class “Alnum”
   "{6,7}" +          // Between 6 and 7 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"$"                // Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
try {
    String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(\\p{Alnum}{3})(\\p{Alnum}{3})\\b", "$1 $2");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the replacement text (unescaped $ signs?)
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Non-existent backreference used the replacement text
}
```

Comment: I need this format "3AB 45D". That is first 3 Alnum chars and space and 3 Alnum chars. How I can achive this?